# Bootstrap grid formatting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to format a slide in a bootstrap that has the format of the following fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozhkav27/3/)

The two divs with "hidden" in them are meant to disappear when on desktop so that when someone is using a tablet or phone they stack on top of each other. This works fine in the fiddle where the height is set to a fixed number

```
height: 100px;
```

But I don't want to set the height this way. If I remove this line you can see in the fiddle that "hidden2" drops down in a weird way instead of acting as a spacer for the text content on the bottom. I've also noticed if I remove the img tag the grid works fine.

I'm not sure why it does this and with real content it just looks like there's no spacer and all the text hugs the left side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You can have a width of the content so there is space on both sides, and using the bootstrap grid system drop the text content down.

HTML

```
<div class="whole">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">text content</div>
</div>>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.whole {
    margin: 0 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understood from your question, you're trying to preserve the functionality found on the fiddle link you provided, but also preserving equal heights. I also understand that you do not want to assign the height manually (i.e in your case, hard-coded).

There are two ways of approaching the solution: Javascript or CSS3.

**Javascript:**

I usually wouldn't solve layout issues with Javascript, but since your scenario has more than **one row** invloved, the easy way is JavaScript. With the help of jQuery, you can iterate through the *div* elements, having an initialized variable (example: var bHeight = 0). Check for each element's height; if it's greater, assign it to **bHeight**.

Your code should something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bHeight = 0;
    $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > bHeight)
            bHeight = $(this).height();
    }); //end of loop

    //now, assign height to all
    $("div").height(bHeight);
});
```

This method will allow you to assign the height of your columns dynamically.

**CSS3:**

A little research online cold introduce you to the CSS3 **display: flex**, yet it's totally up to you to decide regarding browser support ([CSS flex Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)), and more details on solving your issue here: ([A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))